# What is the grammatical term for a "dass"-clause when it is the thing believed?

Tags: grammatical-case, objects

What is the standard grammatical term for the *dass*-clause in the following constructions?

> - glauben, dass P
> - jemanden überzeugen, dass P

The account might look like:

> - The *dass*-clause is the X of *glauben*.
> - The *dass*-clause is the X and the *Jemanden* the Y of *überzeugen*.

on the model of:

> - In `to believe that P`, the *that*-clause is the direct object of *believe*.
> - In `to convince him that P`, the *that*-clause is the direct and *him* the indirect object of *convince*.

**BACKGROUND**

German grammar does not seem to use the "directness" terminology all that much, at least not when the cases would do the job.  For example, a dictionary may say that *sich* in a reflexive verb was in the accusative or dative, not that it was the direct or indirect object.

But in relating a *dass*-clause to a verb such as *glauben* or *überzeugen*, do we still use the concept of case?  For example, do we assign a case to the *dass*-clause?  (Strictly speaking, assigning a case may not relate something to a verb.)

Or do we use the "directness" terminology to say that a *dass*-clause was the direct or indirect object of *glauben* or *überzeugen*?

Or is there some wholly new terminology?

If *überzeugen* followed the model of *convince* I imagine *jemanden* would end up being accusative and indirect.

I don't care if what I said above on English grammar is right or wrong because it is only there as an example.  But see this [Web page](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/verb-patterns/verb-patterns-verb-that-clause) in case you wonder.

Please feel free to answer in German or refer me to a reference page in German.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Forget about direct and indirect objects when it comes to German, please.

The reason why English grammar insists on the "that-clause" being an object is the English top-priority rule **no indirect object without a direct object**. So if an English sentence has an indirect object only, there has to be something declared as the direct object for the sake of keeping that rule valid.

German grammar doesn't have this rule. It doesn't know about direct and indirect objects at all, in fact. There are only accusative, dative, genitive and prepositional objects. It's more general and more complicated as it has to be learned one by one for each verb and meaning.

Of course, the *dass*-clause has a name in German, too. It's called **Objektsatz**. But it isn't limited to *dass*, it can also be introduced by *ob* or a question word - or nothing at all.

> Ich fragte, ob sie kommen könnte.

*I asked if she could come.*

> Sie sagte, sie hätte keine Zeit.

*She said she didn't have time.*

> Er dachte darüber nach, welches Auto er kaufen solle.

*He thought about which car he should buy.*

Again, that's very general and not covered by a single rule.

Comment: Thank you. I am perfectly willing to forget about direct or indirect objects so long as I am told what German grammar calls the *dass*-clauses in the examples. Are you suggesting the case terminology extends to that discussion?

Comment: I edited my answer to cover that. Please look up **Objektsatz**.

Comment: Thanks for directing me in the right direction. I seem to have found out that *dass*-clauses indeed get case assignments (of sorts), depending on the verb. They are said to have *die Funktion eines Akkusativobjekts*, for example, after *verstehen* and *bedauern*. http://www.canoo.net/services/OnlineGrammar/Satz/Komplex/Funktion/Objekt/index.html

Comment: Since we say *jemanden von etwas überzeugen*, perhaps the *dass*-clause in *jemanden überzeugen, dass* will be said to have a genitive function? Do you know?

Comment: No, *von etwas* is preposition+dative. *Ihn vom Gegenteil überzeugen.* → *Ihn davon überzeugen, dass das Gegenteil richtig ist.* So it's a prepositional object. Genitive is used for example with *sicher sein*. *Er war sich seiner Sache sicher.* → *Er war sich sicher, dass seine Sache (sein Vorgehen) richtig ist.*